# How can gather all the results of several findById searches in a single array?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose

Consider the code:

```js
const id=aux[0].healthyTissue[0];
const aux4 = await Hidden.findById(id).populate(
    "children"
);
```

As you may have noticed, `aux` is an array and so is `aux[i].healthyTissue[0]`.

Problem: **I want to gather all the information** *in a single array called `aux4`*, as I am doing for index equal 0, *I want an automatic way to search inside all the arrays*.

I have tried something like `ForEach` and `map`, with no success, I cannot make it wait for the result, it keeps coming empty on the following `res.json`  I thought about `pipe`, however, I could make it work on this case.

Obs. the code showed works, but I want to go through all the elements, gather them in a single array, and return in a `res.json`

Comment: [`forEach` does not work with `await`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37576685/1048572).

Comment: Just don't use `findById`, but a mongoose function that can query multiple elements by a condition?

Comment: you mean `find()` instead?

Comment: I don't know mongodb in detail, but there should be something like `hidden.find({id: {"$in":arr }})`

Comment: No sucess, I have tried `for`, the same problem! It does not wait for the result.

Comment: Please post that code you tried.

Comment: I have decided to follow another strategy, different from this one. Thanks for the attention.